# Highcharts : set a maximum number of ticks with a fixed interval

Tags: highcharts

I would like to be set a fixed interval of 2 hours between every tick on the X axis, but also limit the number of ticks on the whole axis to 5, cropping out the extra data if necessary. 
Currently I can achieve one or the other, but not both, using the following config :

```
tickInterval: 2 * 3600 * 1000 // sets the interval between each tick to 2 hours


tickPixelInterval: 100 // sets the number max number of ticks (for the current graph width) to 5
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/4kps8758/)

Is there a way to achieve both ?

Comment: There is no logical way to achieve what you want. Say you have a paper that is 30 cm long, you can divide this into 6 equal parts of 5 cm (same as setting tickInterval). You cannot at the same time say that you want there to be only 5 parts, but that each part should still be equal to 5 cm. If you want to only show the first 5 ticks and then not show the rest, then I am sure that can be done, and would suggest you edit your question to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks, indeed that was not so clear. I edited the question to clarify that extra data should be cropped out of the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set desired range using `max` or `maxPadding` properties.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.max
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.maxPadding

Examples:
https://jsfiddle.net/vwrpwcq0/ - setting max
https://jsfiddle.net/ztqL9j3g/ - setting maxPadding